# Keep user signed-in always; a la native app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm currently working on a PWA and noticed that the overall experience would be awesome for the users, if they do not have to sign-in every time they open the app.

I've noticed that on native mobile apps, the user stays signed in unless they decide logging out of the app.

I could think about the following approaches -

1. Make the session time super long; say 30 days or 180 days. I'm not aware of the downsides of this approach.
2. Create a cookie that says that auto-login link and use it to authenticate the user automatically when they open the app.

But there could be a way better approach than this; and I'm curious to know about it. Can someone help?

Comment: another option would be to use localStorage. Similar behavior to sessionStorage but without eol.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @MAQU - Is it safe to do that? What techniques do native apps use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well depends on your current user session algorithm, websites like facebook keeps me logged in for years, you might want to use

1. Local storage (Indexed DB) to store the user's data only update them asynchronously ,
2. Cookies, set a (x months) cookie and validate the cookie if it exist probably with the user's data,

This would be preferably done with your server side language and not client side.

Comment: Not sure how could I use IndexedDB from the server side.

Comment: No you don't need to, But if you want to you can through AJAX, I suggest you should take this [jump start](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa) on caching for PWAs